# Run time error 1004 Can't insert new cells because it would push non empty new cells off the end of the worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, runtime, transpose

I have a VBA that was working perfectly fine until I saved it and opened it again, ran it, and started getting the error.

I'm copying data from Sheets("Master") and transposing this data into Sheets("All"). The problem is that I'm transposing it into a table(identified as a list object) and adding a new row before the paste happens. However, for some reason, it'll transpose in odd areas of the sheet. Sometimes at the place it needs to, sometimes at the very last row on Excel. Because of this, I'll get the Run time 1004 error and I have to go in and find this random cells with data. Because this will not be used by me but is a template workbook, I need to make sure it works smoothly.

Here is the code I am using

```
If Sheets("Master").Range("E3") <> "All Agents" Then

Sheets("All").ListObjects("Table24").ListRows.Add
    Sheets("Master").Range("E3").Copy
    Sheets("All").Cells(Sheets("All").Range("A1").ListObject.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Sheets("Master").Range("H3").Copy
    Sheets("All").Cells(Sheets("All").Range("B1").ListObject.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count + 1, 2).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
    Sheets("Master").Range("F9:F33").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    Sheets("All").Cells(Sheets("All").ListObject.DataBodyRange.End(xlDown).Row, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it as,

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Dim wsm As Worksheet, i As Long, v As Long, vals As Variant

    Set wsm = Worksheets("Master")
    If LCase(wsm.Range("E3")) <> "all agents" Then
        v = Application.Subtotal(103, wsm.Range("F9:F33"))
        If CBool(v) Then
            ReDim vals(1 To 1, 1 To v + 2)
            vals(1, 1) = wsm.Range("E3").Value
            vals(1, 2) = wsm.Range("H3").Value
            For i = 1 To v
                vals(1, i + 2) = wsm.Range("F9:F33").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(i)
            Next i

            With Worksheets("All").ListObjects("Table24")
                .ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=False
                .DataBodyRange.Cells(.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, 1).Resize(1, UBound(vals, 2)) = vals
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```